# CSS Flexbox show elements in different rows when they are visible and invisible

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to learn Flexbox and I am having a problem with this exercise. The task is to have a div with 4 div's inside of it. When there are 2 or 3 visible div's they should be divided equal width and all should be the height of the main div. But when all 4 div elements inside the main div are visible, then they would be in two rows which contain two div's each.

How can I make this possible? I have tried some on my own but I couldn't get it to work:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item invisible"></div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS I have created:

```
#wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item{
  min-width: 33%;
}

.invisible{
  display: none;
}
```

Picture of how it should look with 2 elements inside the wrapper Div

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item invisible"></div>
  <div class="item invisible"></div>
</div>
```

[image: 3 elements in the main Div]

Picture of how it should look with 3 elements inside the wrapper Div

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item invisible"></div>
</div>
```

[image: 3 elements in the main Div]

Picture of how it should look with 4 elements inside the wrapper Div

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

[image: 4 elements in the main Div]

Comment: Can you remove/detach the hidden elements from the DOM, or do they have to remain in place?

Comment: can you use the `display: grid` option for your excercise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea using CSS grid. By default I have a column layout with one row from 1 to 3 items and only when there is 4 items the layout change to two rows. To detect this, all the items need to **don't** have invisible class

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-grid;
  vertical-align:top;
  
  grid-auto-columns:1fr;
  grid-auto-flow:column;
  border:5px solid white;
}

.invisible {
  display:none;
}

/* this will select the last item and move it to second row*/
:not(.invisible) + :not(.invisible) + :not(.invisible) + :not(.invisible) {
  grid-row:2;
}

/* this will make sure the blue remain in the first row*/
:first-child:not(.invisible) + :not(.invisible) {
  grid-column:2;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item" style="background:red;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="background:blue;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="background:green;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="background:yellow;"></div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item invisible" style="background:red;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="background:blue;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="background:green;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="background:yellow;"></div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item" style="background:red;"></div>
  <div class="item invisible" style="background:blue;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="background:green;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="background:yellow;"></div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item" style="background:red;"></div>
  <div class="item " style="background:blue;"></div>
  <div class="item invisible" style="background:green;"></div>
  <div class="item " style="background:yellow;"></div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item" style="background:red;"></div>
  <div class="item " style="background:blue;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="background:green;"></div>
  <div class="item invisible" style="background:yellow;"></div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item invisible" style="background:red;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="background:blue;"></div>
  <div class="item invisible" style="background:green;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="background:yellow;"></div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item" style="background:red;"></div>
  <div class="item invisible" style="background:blue;"></div>
  <div class="item invisible" style="background:green;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="background:yellow;"></div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item invisible" style="background:red;"></div>
  <div class="item invisible" style="background:blue;"></div>
  <div class="item " style="background:green;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="background:yellow;"></div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item invisible" style="background:red;"></div>
  <div class="item " style="background:blue;"></div>
  <div class="item " style="background:green;"></div>
  <div class="item invisible" style="background:yellow;"></div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item invisible" style="background:red;"></div>
  <div class="item invisible" style="background:blue;"></div>
  <div class="item invisible" style="background:green;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="background:yellow;"></div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item invisible" style="background:red;"></div>
  <div class="item invisible" style="background:blue;"></div>
  <div class="item " style="background:green;"></div>
  <div class="item invisible" style="background:yellow;"></div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item invisible" style="background:red;"></div>
  <div class="item " style="background:blue;"></div>
  <div class="item invisible" style="background:green;"></div>
  <div class="item invisible" style="background:yellow;"></div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item " style="background:red;"></div>
  <div class="item invisible" style="background:blue;"></div>
  <div class="item invisible" style="background:green;"></div>
  <div class="item invisible" style="background:yellow;"></div>
</div>
```